# Linking different libraries for Debug and Release builds in Cmake on windows?

Tags: c++, windows, cmake

So I've got a library I'm compiling and I need to link different third party things in depending on if it's the debug or release build (specifically the release or debug versions of those libraries).  Is there an easy way to do this in Cmake?

Edit: I should note I'm using visual studio

Answer (score 106, accepted):

According to the [CMake documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_link_libraries.html):

```
target_link_libraries(<target> [lib1 [lib2 [...]]] [[debug|optimized|general] <lib>] ...)
```

> A "debug", "optimized", or "general"
> keyword indicates that the library
> immediately following it is to be used
> only for the corresponding build
> configuration.

So you should be able to do this:

```
add_executable( MyEXE ${SOURCES})

target_link_libraries( MyEXE debug 3PDebugLib)
target_link_libraries( MyEXE optimized 3PReleaseLib)
```

Comment: I do this all the time, even more compactly on one line:

target_link_libraries(MyEXE debug 3PDebugLib optimized 3PReleaseLib)

Comment: What if the library name is the same, but you want visual studio to look for it at a different path? i.e. I want to link mylib.lib but I have two versions of it compiled. one under /path/Debug/mylib.lib and another under /path/Release/mylib.lib (as is often the case with some libraries). What do you do then?

Comment: @Jubei Define 2 variables. One for each library.

Comment: If you want "Release" as in VS 2010 then you need to specify "Release" instead of "optimized" for target_link_libraries. Note that this is case-sensitive. Also you can check for "Release" in your cmake like that: `IF(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE MATCHES Release)` again case sensitive.

Comment: You should not test CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE in the CMake file, it is ignored by multi configuration generators (like VS). If you run cmake with CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug but Release in VS the code in `if(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE MATCHES Release)` is simply ineffective.

Comment: It's adding both the debug *and* release libs when trying the above in  my project...

Comment: And remember the DEBUG_CONFIGURATIONS property that detects which configurations are debug

Comment: @vidstige You have to define this for each library. You can use foreach

Comment: Nope. I get a library called debug.lib and optimized.lib

Answer (score 19):

Somehow the answer from @Mike Willekes got CMake linking in the same target **both release and debug** for me :(

I only got this working by setting both configurations in one line, as suggested by @sakra [in a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6377729/1254880) - and doing so for every library that needed to be linked:

```
target_link_libraries ( app
    debug ${Boost_FILESYSTEM_LIBRARY_DEBUG}
    optimized ${Boost_FILESYSTEM_LIBRARY_RELEASE} )

target_link_libraries ( app
    debug ${Boost_LOG_LIBRARY_DEBUG}
    optimized ${Boost_LOG_LIBRARY_RELEASE} )

target_link_libraries ( app
    debug ${Boost_PROGRAM_OPTIONS_LIBRARY_DEBUG}
    optimized ${Boost_PROGRAM_OPTIONS_LIBRARY_RELEASE} )

# ...
```

Comment: Ah, this is what was happening to me! We only want to link a particular library in release mode, so your method didn't work. In the end I worked around it by using something like the following: `if (CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE STREQUAL "Release")
   target_link_libraries(${ARG_NAME}
     ${LIB_TCMALLOC}
    )
 endif()`

Comment: The drawback, @SteveLorimer, is that in multi config generators - such as for Visual Studio - this would not work as it is done in generate time.

Comment: not sure I understand? We don't link tcmalloc in debug builds. We do link tcmalloc in release builds. That is, there isn't a debug version of tcmalloc, so listing it under optimized only results in it getting linked into debug builds as well

Comment: That's strange, @SteveLorimer. Looking into CMake's docs it's stated that: "The `debug` keyword corresponds to the Debug configuration (...). The `optimized` keyword corresponds to all other configurations." (https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/target_link_libraries.html) What I was saying about multi configuration generators is that the check you put only will work if you generate the project in two separate directories, one for release, the other for debug. In MSVC builds, it makes sense sometimes to  have only one generated directory with the possibility of release and debug builds.

Comment: Ah ok, I see. Well I definitely used `optimized` for the tcmalloc library and it ended up in our debug builds. We use makefiles though... so not sure about VS

Answer (score 10):

I would like to add a few notes to the previous answers.

If you need to create a list of multiple files you want to link and store that in a cache variable then you need to add the `optimized` or `debug` specified before each and every library. This can be especially useful for larger makefiles/projects.

So for example you could do something like this:

```
set( MyFavLib_LIBRARIES 
    debug debug/module1.lib optimized release/module1.lib
    debug debug/module2.lib optimized release/module2.lib )
target_link_libraries( app ${MyFavLib_LIBRARIES} )
```

Answer (score 2):

`target_link_libraries` with `optimize` and `debug` doesn't work for me. I follow the post of Mike Willekes, but release config also import debug library file in visual studio. Then, I use the following cmake code to solving this problem

```
add_library(BoostLib STATIC IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(BoostLib PROPERTIES 
             IMPORTED_LOCATION_DEBUG ${BoostLibPath}/debug/module1.lib
             IMPORTED_LOCATION_RELEASE ${BoostLibPath}/release/module1.lib)

target_link_libraries(AppTarget BoostLib)
```

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me was to use `$(Configuration)` macro in a lib path provided to cmake.

So, assuming libs are stored in separate, correctly named folders, e.g.:

```
C:\boost\lib\Debug\libfoo.lib
C:\boost\lib\Release\libfoo.lib
```

You can then call cmake with:

```
cmake -G "Visual Studio 10 2010" -DBOOST_LIBRARYDIR=C:\boost\lib\$(Configuration)\libfoo.lib
```

That'll generate .vcxproj with Additional Dependencies including `C:\boost\lib\$(Configuration)\libfoo.lib`, what is evaluated to either `C:\boost\lib\Release\libfoo.lib` or `C:\boost\lib\Debug\libfoo.lib` depending on a chosen Configuration.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had to build the external library like this to have both .lib and d.lib in the same directory:

```bash
cmake repo -B build -DCMAKE_DEBUG_POSTFIX=d -DCMAKE_MSVC_RUNTIME_LIBRARY="MultiThreaded$<$<CONFIG:Debug>:Debug>" -A x64 -T v143
cmake --build build --config Debug
cmake --install build --prefix dist --config Debug

cmake --build build --config Release
cmake --install build --prefix dist --config Release
```

Then, simple call to link library went fine:

```bash
target_link_libraries(MyEXE nowide::nowide)
```

This page can help selecting the right version of the library depending on your project configuration: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/MAP_IMPORTED_CONFIG_CONFIG.html#prop_tgt:MAP_IMPORTED_CONFIG_%3CCONFIG%3E