# Link library based on build configuration [cmake]

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Debug and Release Library Linking with CMAKE (VISUAL STUDIO)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5497348/debug-and-release-library-linking-with-cmake-visual-studio)

cmake newb here, I would like to tell target_link_libraries to link a debug lib when using the debug configuration and link to a release lib when compiling under the release configuration.

How do I tell cmake to link a different lib file for the debug configuration?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The solution is:

```
SET(LINK_LIBRARY optimized Foo debug Foo_d)
target_link_libraries(MyEXE ${LINK_LIBRARY})
```

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I was looking for. But now I have to figure out why cmake gives me this error: `Cannot specify link libraries for target "HelloWorld" which is not built by this project.`

Comment: Ah, nvm I was missing `add_library (...)`

Comment: And how to link different libraries for RelWithDebugInfo build configuration?

Answer (score 7):

The [target_link_libraries](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_link_libraries.html) command lets you use keywords which indicate that the library immediately following is to be used only for the corresponding build configuration, e.g.:

```
target_link_libraries(foo debug bard.lib optimized bar.lib)
```

If you add multiple libraries with one `target_link_libraries` statement, the keyword has to be repeated for each library.

Comment: Wasted my entire day and this line saved me: If you add multiple libraries with one target_link_libraries statement, the keyword has to be repeated for each library. cheers