# How do I change the library load *paths* based on the configuration type in cmake?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, cmake, static-libraries

I've got a CMake project where I'd like to link the correct libraries (debug builds get debug libraries; release builds get release libraries) in without having to manually override things. (E.g. once the msbuild bits are constructed by CMake, I want all four targets (Debug, Release, etc.) CMake generates to be able to build without running CMake again)

The CMake documentation (and [other things I've found about this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6377160/link-library-based-on-build-configuration-cmake)) have something along the lines of:

```
SET(LINK_LIBRARY optimized Foo debug Foo_d)
target_link_libraries(MyEXE ${LINK_LIBRARY})
```

However, this changes the library that gets linked based on the file name. Let's say, for the sake of example, that I'm using the Google Test bits included with CMake (FindGTest.cmake, etc), and the Google Test distribution looks like this:

```
 Directory of C:\Foo\gtest-1.6.0\lib

12/30/2011  03:08 PM    <DIR>          Debug
12/30/2011  03:08 PM    <DIR>          Release

 Directory of C:\Foo\gtest-1.6.0\lib\Debug

12/30/2011  03:08 PM         3,388,036 gtest.lib
12/30/2011  03:08 PM           602,112 gtest.pdb
12/30/2011  03:08 PM           131,528 gtest_main.lib
12/30/2011  03:08 PM           389,120 gtest_main.pdb

 Directory of C:\Foo\gtest-1.6.0\lib\Release

12/30/2011  03:08 PM         2,701,324 gtest.lib
12/30/2011  03:08 PM           552,960 gtest.pdb
12/30/2011  03:08 PM           126,364 gtest_main.lib
12/30/2011  03:08 PM           372,736 gtest_main.pdb
```

The example provided in the CMake docs no longer works; the debug and release versions of the library have the same name. Therefore, the example provided in the CMake docs doesn't work -- the names don't differ and that's how the libraries are being specified there. I don't want to have to rename these in the dependent library's build tree (Google Test), because that would add additional steps to get a working build. I want someone to just be able to download Google Test, build it, download my bits, set the environment variable CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH to point at Google Test, and have my library build successfully.

For reference, my current `CMakeLists.txt` looks something like:

```
project( Utilities )
cmake_minimum_required( VERSION 2.8.0 )
file( GLOB Utilities_SourceFiles  "src/*.cpp"  "src/*.rc" "include/utilities/*.h" )
file( GLOB Utilities_TestFiles   "test/*.cpp" "test/*.rc" )

find_package( GTest       REQUIRED )

include_directories( "include/" ${GTEST_INCLUDE_DIRS}))

cxx_library    ( utilities  ${Utilities_SourceFiles} )
cxx_executable ( test       ${Utilities_TestFiles} )
target_link_libraries( test ${GTEST_BOTH_LIBRARIES} )

enable_testing()
GTEST_ADD_TESTS(Test.exe "" ${Utilities_TestFiles})
```

How might I accomplish something like this?

Comment: I'm not sure what are you asking. If look inside FindGTest.cmake, you will see, that it handles opmized and debug versions itself, so when you choose "Debug" in MSVC, it links with debug and for "Release" it's release. Or you wish to implement same thing for your own application? Then just write FindYourApp.cmake by looking at FindGTest.cmake.

Comment: @arrowdodger: Obviously it doesn't do it the right way, because if CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE doesn't match the configuration I choose with MSBuild, the linker fails (with mismatching CRTs).

Comment: Hmm. IIRC, MSVC generator completely ignores CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE set by user and uses CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES. You shoudn't need to rerun CMake to change build type.

Answer (score 1):

For VisualStudio consider setting up multiple configurations at once and make use of different per-configuration [target properties](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/cmake2.6docs.html#section_Properties%20on%20Targets). Also take a look at my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6561754/cmake-changing-name-of-visual-studio-and-xcode-exectuables-depending-on-config) which demonstrates how to setup an output-name based on the currently used configuration.

In addition: setup a new/good find-package script for Googletest and use the IMPORTED option for [add_library](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/cmake2.6docs.html#command:add_library). With it, you can define a single library target `Foo` and you can set its properties (location, filename, etc.) for each configuration:

```
# Assuming the Foo-root dir is defined in FOO_DIR
add_library( Foo IMPORTED )
# You can define two import-locations: one for debug and one for release.
set_target_properties( Foo PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION_DEBUG ${FOO_DIR}/Debug/Foo_d.lib
set_target_properties( Foo PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION_RELEASE ${FOO_DIR}/Release/Foo.lib
```

So, all in all:

1. When building you own libraries, internal to your project, make use of the output properties [OUTPUT_NAME](http://cmake.org/cmake/help/cmake-2-8-docs.html#prop_tgt:OUTPUT_NAME) and the various [ARCHIVE_](http://cmake.org/cmake/help/cmake-2-8-docs.html#prop_tgt:ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY), [RUNTIME_](http://cmake.org/cmake/help/cmake-2-8-docs.html#prop_tgt:RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY), [LIBRARY_](http://cmake.org/cmake/help/cmake-2-8-docs.html#prop_tgt:LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY), output properties which all have per-configuration variants.
2. When linking to 3rdparty libraries, make use of the import properties where [IMPORTED_LOCATION](http://cmake.org/cmake/help/cmake-2-8-docs.html#prop_tgt:IMPORTED_LOCATION) is especially important and its per-configuration variants.