# cmake: multiple debug/opt libraries in single target_link_libraries()

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake

My question is related to [Link library based on build configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6377160/link-library-based-on-build-configuration-cmake/6377729#6377729) and [Debug and Release Library Linking with CMAKE (VISUAL STUDIO)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5497348/debug-and-release-library-linking-with-cmake-visual-studio), however the answers were not satisfying.

My goal is to have one variable where to specify the path to libraries similar to

```
SET(LINK_LIBRARY optimized Foo debug Foo_d)
target_link_libraries(MyEXE ${LINK_LIBRARY})
```

But what I want is to have one variable for a bunch of libraries, that I can dispatch to a single call to `target_link_libaries()`. So something like

```
SET(LINK_LIBRARIES optimized Foo Foo1 Foo2 debug Foo_d Foo1_d Foo2_d)
target_link_libraries(MyEXE ${LINK_LIBRARIES})
```

But all over the internet I find that this is not possible in this way, i.e. that I always have to write

```
target_link_libraries(MyEXE optimized Foo optimized Foo1 debug Foo_d debug Foo1_d)
```

which means I can't just put all the libraries in one single variable `LINK_LIBRARIES`, but need `FOO_LIBRARY`, `FOO1_LIBRARY` aso.

Is there a way to do this or do I always have to create one variable per single library?

Comment: It is unclear what problem you have so I assume your problem is scope. I mean I only create 1 variable for this in my root CMakeLists.txt and use in all of my executables.

Comment: Oh ok, I added a more verbose description, hopefully now it is more clear what I mean.

Comment: ***But all over the internet I find that this is not possible in this way*** This is wrong. Or at least I have done it that way.

Comment: lol you're totally right, it works this way, should have just tried it.

Comment: BTW, these days I am migrating from this method to using IMPORTED / EXPORTED targets like this: http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake/Tutorials/Exporting_and_Importing_Targets

Comment: Cool, thank you for the comment, I'll investigate that :)