# Using protobuf with CMake's different build configurations (RelWithDebugInfo and Debug)

Tags: cmake, protocol-buffers

In my project I'm using protobuf 3.5. I need at least the debug and the `RelWithDebugInfo` configurations. To be able to build the project with protobuf debug libraries led to some problems alone:

I needed to build the protobuf libraries from source using both the release and the debug target since the `_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL` of my libraries (`= 2`) didn't match the level of the protobuf libraries (`= 0`). After building the debug libraries as well as the release libraries, compiling in debug configuration was possible.

Now, after changing back to `RelWithDebugInfo` I get the same error again, but now just the opposite: The `_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL` of my libraries is `0` and the level of the used protobuf libraries is `2`.

When checking the linker configuration, I can see that my libraries are linked against the libprotobuf**d**.lib. This makes sense since I've read somewhere that everything which is *not* `Release` will use the debug libraries, if available. And this leads to my problem:

I won't build my libraries in `Release` during development. It's most of the time `RelWithDebugInfo`. But the `_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL` for this configuration is obviously set to `0` (because it *is* a release configuration with additional information). But CMake then links against protobuf's debug libraries which are not compatible with the rest.

I'm now looking for a possibility to tell CMake to not use the debug version of the libraries but the release version instead *without changing the CMake scripts of protobuf itself*.

Normally my way to go would be to [link different libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5497348/debug-and-release-library-linking-with-cmake-visual-studio) depending on the actual build configuration. But unfortunately, the protobuf CMake configuration tries to handle this by itself.

```
# Load information for each installed configuration.
get_filename_component(_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_FILE}" PATH)
file(GLOB CONFIG_FILES "${_DIR}/protobuf-targets-*.cmake")
foreach(f ${CONFIG_FILES})
  include(${f})
endforeach()
```

whilst the imported target is <del>overwritten</del> selected depending on the actual configuration:

*protobuf-targets-release.cmake:*

```
# Import target "protobuf::libprotobuf-lite" for configuration "Release"
set_property(TARGET protobuf::libprotobuf-lite APPEND PROPERTY IMPORTED_CONFIGURATIONS RELEASE)
set_target_properties(protobuf::libprotobuf-lite PROPERTIES
  IMPORTED_LINK_INTERFACE_LANGUAGES_RELEASE "CXX"
  IMPORTED_LOCATION_RELEASE "${_IMPORT_PREFIX}/lib/libprotobuf-lite.lib"
  )
```

*protobuf-targets-debug.cmake:*

```
# Import target "protobuf::libprotobuf-lite" for configuration "Debug"
set_property(TARGET protobuf::libprotobuf-lite APPEND PROPERTY IMPORTED_CONFIGURATIONS DEBUG)
set_target_properties(protobuf::libprotobuf-lite PROPERTIES
  IMPORTED_LINK_INTERFACE_LANGUAGES_DEBUG "CXX"
  IMPORTED_LOCATION_DEBUG "${_IMPORT_PREFIX}/lib/libprotobuf-lited.lib"
  )
```

whereas the linking in my CMakeLists.txt looks like this:

```
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE
    protobuf::libprotobuf
    protobuf::libprotoc
)
```

I don't see any possibility here to specify the desired library. Normally I'd say I would specify it somehow like this:

```
target_link_libraries(MyEXE
    debug protobuf::libprotobufd optimized protobuf::libprotobuf
    debug protobuf::libprotocd optimized protobuf::libprotoc)
```

or wrap some fancy if-condition for the different build configurations around it. But due to protobuf effectively overwriting the target, I don't know how to extract the correct library for each build.

Any ideas?

Comment: "But due to protobuf effectively overwriting the target" - No, the target is not overwritten. It is their properties which are assigned, but all of them are different (different suffix). The only same property is *IMPORTED_CONFIGURATIONS*, but it is *APPEND*'ed, not overwitten. What you are looking for is [CMAKE_MAP_IMPORTED_CONFIG_<CONFIG>](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/variable/CMAKE_MAP_IMPORTED_CONFIG_CONFIG.html) variables, which "map" configurations of your project to the imported configurations.

Comment: Sorry, yes! You are absolutely correct! This means I can put the mapping command into a if condition and do something like this:
`if (build == RelWithDebugInfo) then CMAKE_MAP_IMPORTED_CONFIG_RELEASE`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm now looking for a possibility to tell CMake to not use the debug version of the libraries but the release version instead

Variables [CMAKE_MAP_IMPORTED_CONFIG_](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/variable/CMAKE_MAP_IMPORTED_CONFIG_CONFIG.html) are intended for resolve exactly that problem:

```
# When build your project in RelWithDebugInfo configuration,
# try to use Release configuration of the *IMPORTED* libraries.
# If some IMPORTED library has no Release configuration, fallback to Debug one.
set(CMAKE_MAP_IMPORTED_CONFIG_RELWITHDEBUGINFO Release Debug)

# Imported targets set with given call will be aware of the variable's set above
find_package(Protobuf REQUIRED)

# Simply link with an IMPORTED library. 
target_link_libraries(MyExe protobuf::libprotobuf)
```

If you want to use Release configuration **only** from the **specific** IMPORTED libraries, but not all, you may set corresponded **properties** for these specific libraries:

```
# Firstly, create needed IMPORTED target.
find_package(Protobuf REQUIRED)

# Then adjust its properties.
# While the target is created by others, given property is specifically
# designed to be set in *your project*.
set_property(TARGET protobuf::libprotobuf PROPERTY MAP_IMPORTED_CONFIG_RELWITHDEBUGINFO Release Debug)

# Simply link with an IMPORTED library. 
target_link_libraries(MyExe protobuf::libprotobuf)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! This works fine now. It only took me another hour to find out that the build configuration is named `RelWithDebInfo` and *not* `RelWithDebugInfo` as I thought at first.

Man, it would be lovely if CMake would be *a little bit* more verbose when variables are not set...