# Specifying different libraries for Debug & Release mode

Tags: visual-studio, cmake

I'm trying to write a `CMakeLists.txt` file so that it generates a Visual Studio solution. I have several external libraries, and some libraries have different import libraries for Debug & Release mode.

In Visual Studio, I'd manually select each mode, and change the name of the library and the required directory. I think I need to play with `target_link_libraries` and `set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Release)` but I haven't had any luck so far.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Linking different libraries for Debug and Release builds in Cmake on windows?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2209929/linking-different-libraries-for-debug-and-release-builds-in-cmake-on-windows)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `target_link_libraries` command supports "debug" and "optimized" keywords, which indicate that the library immediately following it is to be used only for the corresponding build configuration:

```
target_link_libraries(MyTarget debug externalLib_d optimized externalLib)
```

If the debug and release libraries reside in different directories, specify the full path, i.e.:

```
target_link_libraries(MyTarget debug "debug_dir/externalLib_d" optimized "release_dir/externalLib")
```

Also see the [target_link_libraries command documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_link_libraries.html).

Comment: Thanks! That works. But is it possible to ensure that the link directories for the Release & Debug mode are different as well? It's not mandatory, but it would be nice.

Comment: @Jacob: I hope I understood your question correctly, see updated answer.