# CMake - Linking different libraries for Debug and Release builds with variable from find_package

Tags: c++, cmake

I would like to link to certain libraries only in Debug builds, not in Release ones. Using the `debug` flag in `target_link_libraries` as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5586389/specifying-different-libraries-for-debug-release-mode) only applies to the library immediately following the flag. However, I would like to apply it to all libraries specified in a variable from `find_package`, like so:

```
find_package(Cairomm)
add_library(Paint Painter.cpp)
target_link_libraries(Paint
  debug ${Cairomm_LIBRARIES}
```

Checking the resulting binary with `ldd` shows, that the first library specified in `Cairomm_LIBRARIES` is indeed omitted, the following however are linked.

Can I somehow apply the `debug` flag to all libraries in the variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a loop:

```
foreach (_lib ${Cairomm_LIBRARIES})
    target_link_libraries(Paint debug ${_lib})
endforeach()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that did the trick. After some refactoring, I pulled all the Cairo related stuff in its own .cpp and created a separate library target for it that I could then use with debug in target_link_library.