# CMake Visual Studio Debug/Release find_package

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake

I use cmake to build on Windows, Linux, and OSX. On Windows, I use .dll and .lib files that I have prebuilt and put it in a folder project/windows/bin, project/windows/include, and project/windows/lib. These folders house all my third party dependencies for windows. In my CMakeLists.txt, I use:

```
if(WIN32)
  set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/windows)
endif()

find_package(SDL2 REQUIRED)
find_package(GLEW REQUIRED)
```

It works but I am only able to use one configuration of the library. I would like to be able to link different configuration of the library like Debug and Release.

The question is : 
How do I make it so that when I set my visual studio project to debug, it will use the debug version of the library and use the release version of the libray when I set the visual studio project to release?

Do I need to set up my /windows library directory differently?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does [this SO question/answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2209929/linking-different-libraries-for-debug-and-release-builds-in-cmake-on-windows) address your question?

Answer (score 2):

I'm now sure, whether the `FindSDL2` and `FindGLEW` modules you use provide [imported targets](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.5/manual/cmake-buildsystem.7.html#imported-targets). If so, then might pick up the respective library as both debug and release and you should use the imported target for linking.

Otherwise, you have two options:

1. Explicitly use `optimized <LIB1_release> debug <LIB1_debug>` as referenced by @aichao in the other SO question/answer:

   ```
   target_link_libraries(MyConsumerTarget
                         PUBLIC optimized <LIB1_release>
                                debug <LIB1_debug>)
   ```
2. Manually create imported library targets for each external library and use them for linking:

   ```
   if(NOT TARGET External::lib1) # this if is required for subsequent runs of CMake
     add_library(External::lib1 SHARED IMPORTED GLOBAL)
     set_target_properties(External::lib1
                           PROPERTIES INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/windows/include"
                                      IMPORTED_LINK_INTERFACE_LANGUAGES "C"
                                      IMPORTED_LOCATION_RELEASE "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/windows/bin/<LIB1_release>.dll"
                                      IMPORTED_IMPLIB_RELEASE "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/windows/lib/<LIB1_release_importlib>.lib"
                                      IMPORTED_LOCATION_DEBUG "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/windows/bin/<LIB1_debug>.dll"
                                      IMPORTED_IMPLIB_DEBUG "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/windows/lib/<LIB1_debug_importlib>.lib")
    endif()

    target_link_libraries(MyConsumerTarget
                          Public External::lib1)
   ```

---

Personally, I prefer the latter as it is less verbose in the main CMakeLists file. The definition of the different libraries can be done in other files included via other means.
Usually, I have a directory `3rdparty` in my projects with a `CMakeLists.txt` file, which pulls in external projects and defines such imported targets. In the main CMake file I can then easily use these imported targets.