# Adding different include directory for Debug and Release builds in Cmake?

Tags: cmake

I'm developing a library and I need to add a third party header-only library for debug build only. It's only used for development.

Is there an easy way to do this in CMake?

I know we can [do the same for linking libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2209929/3427520),

```
add_executable( MyEXE ${SOURCES})

target_link_libraries( MyEXE debug 3PDebugLib)
target_link_libraries( MyEXE optimized 3PReleaseLib)
```

But there seems no such option for `target_include_directories`.

Using CMake 3.11.4 and VS2017.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While `target_include_directories` itself does not provide the possibility to distinguish between different build types, you can use [generator expressions](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.11/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html), e.g.:

```
target_include_directories(MyEXE
    PRIVATE
        $<$<CONFIG:Debug>:3PDebugLib>
        $<$<CONFIG:Release>:3PReleaseLib>
)
```

Comment: target_include_directories (foo_exe PRIVATE
        $<IF$<CONFIG:Debug>:debug_dir,release_dir>)